# when hierarchy is enabled can i update all child account records when a parent account is updated?

Tags: account, hierarchy

Both Parent and the Child are technically Account.
Can i use Process Builder to update a field on all the child records when a field on parent account is updated?

We have Hierarchy enabled and also junction object(Related Business) between Business and Business. Three Levels of hierarchy defined with Record types. Record Type1, Record Type2, Record Type3. We have a Process Builder on Junction Object (Related Business ) to check for field value change on Record type1 and update it on Record Type 2. But its not working

Comment: child or children and grandchildren?  Did you try anything?  PB has a feature to set all children for field X of an object to a fixed val

Comment: please use [edit] and amend your post with additional details. include PB screen shots, schema depiction, and observed behavior. Avoid using comments.